# Creating Multiple APK with different icons and SplashScreen from same Sourcefile in React-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk

I'm trying to create Multiple APK from same source file with different Icons

```
 eg: APP_ONE , APP_TWO , APP_THREE
```

1) I need to install all these APPS(1,2,3) on the same device with different icons

Now i'm creating these APKs from different projects with same source(Copy&Paste src from main to all other projects)

> When i put the src file outside from all projects it's showing path
>   error.So is there is any solution for avoiding this copy&paste of
>   src.How to make this src as common to all projects ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `Flavors` inside the `build.gradle` file of app module of the Android project (And add configutations for the iOS part).

This [article](https://medium.com/@ywongcode/building-multiple-versions-of-a-react-native-app-4361252ddde5) could be helpful.